# Keep GtkFrame label widget enabled when frame is not

Tags: c++, gtk

I am using gtk2 and have a checkbox as the label widget in my frame.

I want to be able to enable/disable the frame based on the checkbox state. However, when I disable the frame (using `gtk_widget_set_sensitive(frame, false)`), it also disables the checkbox in the frame label.

Is there anyway to keep the label permanently enabled or re-enable it specifically when the frame is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set the frames child widget insensitive instead, or have a I missed something?

In any case a widget can only be sensitive if its parent is sensitive: there's no way around this.